# IOS change bundle identifer for google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I wanna use google maps in my IOS application

I got a key with this projectID `com-vmp-roma`

However, my bundle identifier is `com.romatest.testgooglemap.` and the project name in xcode is `tableviewtutorial`

I must change the identifer of my project to match the project id that I have used when getting the key.

#### what I have tried

So I read through internet and I found that I have to :

1. right click on the project
2. show package content
3. double click on the `project.pbxproj`
4. in the `Begin PBXBuildFile section` change the `productName` to be `com-vmp-roma`
5. clean and rebuild.

But, I just can see the marker of the map, the map is not showing: help please

#### Edit

this is what I see
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can look the link: [[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=vi]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=vi%5d)
Register your app by your bundle identifier : com.romatest.testgooglemap. Get iOS API key and use method

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
```

at your AppDelegate.

Comment: I alreday did that my firends. I can see the maker but the map is not showing,   I know the problem, it is because different identifers in my project and in code google api.